# When do inline scripts execute when using JQuery.html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am inserting HTML as well as some inline javascript with JQuery's html() function.

It seems that JQuery.html() is a synchronous function, but it does not guarantee that inline scripts are done executing before proceeding.

So for example:

```
$elem.html(some_html_with_inline_scripts);
function_that_relies_on_inline_scripts_done_executing();
```

Does not work because my inline scripts are executing AFTER the function call.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Older versions of jQuery didn't execute scripts in the `.html()` function because it was essentially a fancy version of `.innerHTML`. A fix had to be introduced to execute scripts at all. You're better off including script dependencies via `jQuery.getScript`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for a workaround?

```
var scripts_loaded = false; //set this true at end of some_html_with_inline_scripts
$elem.html(some_html_with_inline_scripts);

function are_scripts_loaded() {
 if (scripts_loaded) {
  clearInterval(intid);
  function_that_relies_on_inline_scripts_done_executing();
 }
}
var intid = setInterval(are_scripts_loaded, 10);
```

This tests every 10 milliseconds if the scripts are loaded. You may want to increase it from 10 to something else.

Comment: That's an ugly workaround. Unfortunately, I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Well, if it was pretty, you wouldn't call it a workaround. If the element being loaded has a url, like `<img>` or `<iframe>`, then `$elem.on('load', function() {});` could be used